# Should I declare one or two tables to represent Items and Sub Items?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm facing a dilemma in my database design for an *upholstery store*.

- This store cleans *carpets, pillows, car seats, car trunks, couches*.
- There are *chairs* and *sofas* with *fixed* and *removable seat cushions*. *Car seats* and *trunks* with different *sizes*. The same occurs with *pillows*.

From my point of view all of these things are *items*. My idea is to create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    ItemID …
    Name …
    Description …
    Material … -- (like 'cotton', 'wool', 'rayon', 'silk')
    Length …
    Height …
    Width …
);
```

The *items* mentioned earlier have *sub items*. A *car* has *seats* and *trunk*. A *chair* can have a *fixed* or a *removable seat*, a *couch* can have *pillows* and so on.

I've read these posts:

- [Sub and sub sub items organization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96631/sub-and-sub-sub-item-organization-system)
- [What is Parent/Child relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880921/what-is-a-parent-table-and-a-child-table-in-database)
- [Parent/Child relationship best practice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142138/best-practice-for-parent-child-relation)
- [Items with sub items](https://www.webmasterworld.com/databases_sql_mysql/4408859.htm)

After reading them, I have some questions:

1. Is it a good idea to include another column called `subItem` which references a *parent* `item` from the same table? Doing that it hurts performance?
2. Is this a case of a `parent/child` table?

I'm wondering what approach fits simpler for maintenance and performance.

Comment: That would depend on the business requirements.  If the business wants to track the car that is associated with car seats that are repaired, then you would need the parent/child schema.  If it were my business I wouldn't bother with that, but you might ask your instructor.  It's not an issue of maintenance and performance, it would be an issue of employees spending time collecting and entering the data, and also additional time spent by developers to build the application.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a straightforward one-to-many relationship, which as you suggested you can model by setting a foreign key in the child items table referring to the parent items table. As for performance, you won't have any kind of performance hit at all for a small site. Modelling your schema properly is your priority.

Consider renaming the tables too. For example, if the shop offers a cleaning service then you could think of the tables in terms of Services (e.g. car) and Costs (seats, trunk, etc)